# Why do the first two assignment statements in my method run twice continuously?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

```py
    def step(self, t, action):
        done = (True if (self.state == self.T) else False)
        self.state += 1
        self.S[self.state] = self.lFn()
        return self.state, self.getReward(t, action), done
```

I am working on a reinforcement learning project in Python 3.9 and have encountered an issue with my `step` method in a class. When I run the code, the first two assignment statements in the method seem to run twice continuously. I am new to writing object-oriented content in Python and am unsure if this is due to an issue in my code or the nature of the Python kernel. I would appreciate any guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Don't post code as images. Embed it in your question as a codeblock. Also, include a minimal, complete, reproducible and verifiable example. If you don't, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: could you show more of the code, maybe where you call this method?

Comment: @Mayfair Thanks quite a lot. The problem was solved. I just found that I had deleted a breakpoint in the previous code, causing me to look at just this piece and think that it was running multiple times within a single call, when in fact it was the loop body of the call that was executed multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

The (completely uninteresting) answer is: line 140 contains an `if` statement and an assignment. They are executed sequentially; there is no easy way for a debugger to tell you what part of the line is being executed, thus the line is "executed twice".

A more concise way to write this, which will also look natural in the debugger, is:

```py
done = self.state == self.T
```

Comment: Got it.  It's always nice to see a more concise expression.